# ¿Qué significa "Su rama está por encima del origin/master"?

Tags: linux, git, github

¿Por que en Git me aparece el siguiente mensaje?

> Su rama está por encima del origin/master

¿Qué significa?

Comment: Esta pregunta fue reportada como de baja calidad por su contenido. Esto está al borde de ser una muy mala pregunta pero creo que es una pregunta válida :\ , te recomendaría al menos leer los manuales de Git ya que la respuesta es parte fundamental del funcionamiento del control de versiones, debes poner un poco de tu parte también (y para el que tenga esta misma duda ¬¬).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Su rama está por encima del origin/master

Has hecho `git commit` pero no has hecho `git push`, por lo tanto hay cambios que aun no fueron *subidos* al origen (ej GitHub).

Si haces `git push`, sincronizarás el repositiorio, enviando los últimos commits al origen.

También puede decir:

> Su rama está por debajo/detrás del origin/master

Esto significa que otra persona ha hecho `git commit` y `git push` al origen pero que aún no has descargando los cambios. Una forma de hacerlo sería hacer `git pull` para sincronizarte. Pero no es la única.

También puede decir una mezcla de los dos mensajes.